# Call one function of the same component in which function is defines in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have created one common util file to write some common foundations like below.

```
export default { 
    a: () => {
        console.log("Hello");
    }

    b: () => {
        this.a();
    }
}
```

I want to call the function into the function b. I have tried lots of things but none of them are working. Please help me in this concern.

Comment: With an arrow function the `this` will not be respecting to that object but to the context above. The arrow functions bubble the context up. Use the function key word instead and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can definetly do this.

```js
var xxx = { 
    a: () => {
        console.log("Hello");
    },

    b: () => {
        xxx.a();
    }
}
xxx.b();
```

But i dont know why you want it like that.

Answer (score 0):

As you want `export` this util functionality, so write the following code in `util.js` file.

```
export default class Util{
    a = () => {
        console.log("Hello");
    };

    b = () => {
        this.a();
    }
}
```

and where you want to `import` this code, you can use as below:

```
import Util from './util.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like:

```
    const a = () => {
      console.log("Hey it's A");
    }

    const b = () => {
      a();
      console.log("Hey it's B");
    }

    export { a, b };
```